# Recording Audio on iOS 7 with AVAudioRecorder and keeping sound file saved for playback on App Restart

Tags: objective-c, audio, ios7, record, playback

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_iOS_7_with_AVAudioRecorder) and have it all working, however when I fully close the app (by double tap on home and swiping it up) and reopening it, the recorded sound from the last session is gone.Here's the relevant code:

RecordViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface RecordViewController : UIViewController
    <AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *recordButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
- (IBAction)recordAudio:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender;

@end
```

RecordViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   _playButton.enabled = NO;
   _stopButton.enabled = NO;

   NSArray *dirPaths;
   NSString *docsDir;

   dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

   NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

   NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
            dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
            AVEncoderBitRateKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
            AVSampleRateKey,
            nil];

   NSError *error = nil;

   AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
   [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord 
    error:nil];

  _audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error];

   if (error)
   {
           NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
   } else {
           [_audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
   }
}

- (IBAction)recordAudio:(id)sender {
     if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
     {
             _playButton.enabled = NO;
             _stopButton.enabled = YES;
             [_audioRecorder record];
     }
}

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
    {
       _stopButton.enabled = YES;
       _recordButton.enabled = NO;

        NSError *error;

        _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
        initWithContentsOfURL:_audioRecorder.url
        error:&error];

        _audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        if (error)
              NSLog(@"Error: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
        else
              [_audioPlayer play];
   }
}

- (IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender {
    _stopButton.enabled = NO;
    _playButton.enabled = YES;
    _recordButton.enabled = YES;

    if (_audioRecorder.recording)
    {
            [_audioRecorder stop];
    } else if (_audioPlayer.playing) {
            [_audioPlayer stop];
    }
}

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
        _recordButton.enabled = YES;
        _stopButton.enabled = NO;
}

-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player 
error:(NSError *)error
{
        NSLog(@"Decode Error occurred");
}

-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:
(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder 
successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
}

-(void)audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur:
(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder 
error:(NSError *)error
{
        NSLog(@"Encode Error occurred");
}
```

I know the viewDidLoad is resetting it but I am unsure how to change the code to avoid that, save the file and have it available for playback if it already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging around similar topics I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387237/xcode-how-to-save-audio-file-after-recording-audio-using-avfoundation) in which user [Paul Brady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256924/paul-brady) states that the following code is overriding the file and thus should be removed so when the app reopens, the file is accessible:  "[recorder prepareToRecord]"